# Can't delete directory under Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows

I want to delete a directory under Windows 7 from Explorer, but every time I do so I get an error window with the message "Could not find this item" and "This is no longer located in ...".

The file is not in use, I can change into the directory (it's empty), reboot doesn't help, clicking "Try again" doesn't help, deleting from CMD.EXE doesn't work. I cannot rename it as well.

What can I do to delete the directory?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever the reason for the malfunction is, but it seems it has something to do with the long file names.

The solution that worked: start CMD.EXE, change into the *containing* directory, **type "dir /x" to display the short file names**, then use the short file name to delete the directory. Done. :)

Comment: Nice solution I have not seen before for this issue.